# Underlay Following Sections based on the formula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with pageheadersection1.
    Within this page header, there is a picture object which I want to use as a watermark.

I have a parameter field ( IncludeWaterMark Boolean).

```
If IncludeWaterMark  = False:
```

I don't want to underlay page header and also want to suppress the picture object.

```
if IncludeWaterMark Parameter is true:
```

I want to underlay page header section and not suppress the picture object.

So far I tried to suppress and use the checkbox underlay following section using a formula:

```
If {?IncludeWaterMark} then true else false.
```

But this doesn't work. it's always including a watermark even when the IncludeWatermark is passed as false in vb.net code.

Please help!

Comment: Paste your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page header section check underlay following sections also suppress if blank section. On the picture object suppress using a formula : if {includeWaterMark} = false then true else false